# E/CRASH(7870): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000007c2f67f818

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

This is a repost because i haven't had any traction on the unity forums, so posing the same issue to a wider audience, been stuck on this one for a few days now

I've been having troubles recently with my apps in alpha on the play store. I have been doing a bit of work recently and just using the Run and Build option inside of Unity to test that my application is working correctly however, i've been a bit stumped with this issue.

When i attempt to download my app off the playstore (Closed Alpha) the application seems to install without any issues but the moment it opens it immediately closes.

I've hooked up my phone to my pc and run the adb logcat in cmd as well as the monitor from tools and i get the following crash when i attempt to open it:

i've edited my fingerprint and company name

```
09-21 07:42:05.103: E/CRASH(7870): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000007c2f67f818

09-21 07:42:05.103: E/CRASH(7870): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

09-21 07:42:05.103: E/CRASH(7870): Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'

09-21 07:42:05.103: E/CRASH(7870): Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus3/OnePlus3T:9/***********/**********:user/release-keys'

09-21 07:42:05.103: E/CRASH(7870): Revision: '0'

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870): pid: 7870, tid: 9955, name: UnityMain  >>> com.Company.Game <<<

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870):     x0   00000079ff9c67d8  x1   0000000000000007  x2   0000007a9e1ec560  x3   0000000000cdb330

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870):     x4   00000000001c8b08  x5   0000000000ce3330  x6   00000000001ccb08  x7   e661aa1c417c1492

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870):     x8   00000000464c457f  x9   00000079fd05cc20  x10  0000000000539a10  x11  00000000000000e4

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870):     x12  e661aa1c417c1492  x13  00000000000000d5  x14  00000000000000d5  x15  0000007a9e1a8cc0

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870):     x16  0000007a9e1e31e0  x17  0000007a9e0e34b8  x18  0000000000000004  x19  00000079ff7fcdb0

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870):     x20  00000079fb84e6d8  x21  00000079fd283000  x22  00000079fd023530  x23  00000079fd283000

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870):     x24  00000079fd283000  x25  00000079fd283000  x26  00000000000002d4  x27  00000079fb84e6d4

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870):     x28  0000000000000ae5  x29  00000079ff7fce30  x30  00000079fbef29f4

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870):     sp   00000079ff7fcda0  pc   00000079fbef29e0  pstate 0000000000000000

09-21 07:42:05.104: E/CRASH(7870): backtrace:

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000007c2f76e818

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993): Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993): Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus3/OnePlus3T:9/**********/*********:user/release-keys'

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993): Revision: '0'

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993): pid: 9993, tid: 10035, name: UnityMain  >>> com.Company.Game <<<

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993):     x0   00000079ff9ec7d8  x1   0000000000000007  x2   0000007a9e1ec560  x3   0000000000cda6a0

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993):     x4   00000000001c7748  x5   0000000000ce26a0  x6   00000000001cb748  x7   e661aa1c417c1492

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993):     x8   00000000464c457f  x9   00000079fd14bc20  x10  0000000000539a10  x11  00000000000000e4

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993):     x12  e661aa1c417c1492  x13  00000000000000d8  x14  00000000000000d8  x15  0000007a9e1a8cc0

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993):     x16  0000007a9e1e31e0  x17  0000007a9e0e34b8  x18  0000000000000004  x19  00000079ff7fcdb0

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993):     x20  00000079fb93d6d8  x21  00000079fd372000  x22  00000079fd112530  x23  00000079fd372000

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993):     x24  00000079fd372000  x25  00000079fd372000  x26  00000000000002d4  x27  00000079fb93d6d4

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993):     x28  0000000000000ae5  x29  00000079ff7fce30  x30  00000079fbfe19f4

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993):     sp   00000079ff7fcda0  pc   00000079fbfe19e0  pstate 0000000000000000

09-21 07:42:34.377: E/CRASH(9993): backtrace:

09-21 07:42:34.403: E/CRASH(9993):     #00  pc 000000000000068c  [vdso] ()

09-21 07:42:34.403: E/CRASH(9993):     #01  pc 00000000006a19dc  /data/app/com.Company.Game-lZRPnhDcySTa8I_G8bddEg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 07:42:34.403: E/CRASH(9993):     #02  pc 00000000006a157c  /data/app/com.Company.Game-lZRPnhDcySTa8I_G8bddEg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 07:42:34.403: E/CRASH(9993):     #03  pc 00000000006a9680  /data/app/com.Company.Game-lZRPnhDcySTa8I_G8bddEg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 07:42:34.404: E/CRASH(9993):     #04  pc 0000000000676d8c  /data/app/com.Company.Game-lZRPnhDcySTa8I_G8bddEg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 07:42:34.404: E/CRASH(9993):     #05  pc 00000000003386bc  /data/app/com.Company.Game-lZRPnhDcySTa8I_G8bddEg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 07:42:34.404: E/CRASH(9993):     #06  pc 00000000002da0a0  /data/app/com.Company.Game-lZRPnhDcySTa8I_G8bddEg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 07:42:34.404: E/CRASH(9993):     #07  pc 00000000002da9b4  /data/app/com.Company.Game-lZRPnhDcySTa8I_G8bddEg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 07:42:34.404: E/CRASH(9993):     #08  pc 00000000002d3b1c  /data/app/com.Company.Game-lZRPnhDcySTa8I_G8bddEg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 07:42:34.404: E/CRASH(9993):     #09  pc 0000000000000d7c  /data/app/com.Company.Game-lZRPnhDcySTa8I_G8bddEg==/oat/arm64/base.odex ()
```

Info logs with Unity Tag on it:

```
09-21 08:11:40.322: I/Unity(15669): SystemInfo CPU = ARM64 FP ASIMD AES, Cores = 4, Memory = 5738mb

09-21 08:11:40.322: I/Unity(15669): SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 2 big (mask: 0xc), 2 little (mask: 0x3)

09-21 08:11:40.322: I/Unity(15669): ApplicationInfo com.Company.Game version 0.11 build b6058604-4beb-45ab-81d6-13bed6aa8d13

09-21 08:11:40.322: I/Unity(15669): Built from '2019.2/staging' branch, Version '2019.2.0f1 (20c1667945cf)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a', Stripping 'Enabled'
```

i've been doing some reading on this and one of the recommended fixes was in this thread:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-crash-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-on-some-devices

which suggests that you turn off stripping and enable debug mode on the C++ Compiler Configuration.

After re-building and placing on the app store i then get a new error:

```
09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (?), fault addr --------

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669): Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669): Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus3/OnePlus3T:9/*********/**********:user/release-keys'

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669): Revision: '0'

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669): pid: 15669, tid: 15688, name: UnityMain  >>> com.Company.Game <<<

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669):     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000003d48  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669):     x4   0000000000000080  x5   0000000000000080  x6   0000000000000080  x7   0000000000000040

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669):     x8   0000000000000083  x9   e661aa1c417c1492  x10  fffffff87ffffbdf  x11  e661aa1c417c1492

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669):     x12  e661aa1c417c1492  x13  fffffff87ffffbdf  x14  000000005d854e9c  x15  0000000000000008

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669):     x16  0000007a9e1e32b0  x17  0000007a9e0f5088  x18  e661aa1c417c1492  x19  0000000000003d35

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669):     x20  0000000000003d48  x21  0000000000000083  x22  00000079ff3fd978  x23  00000079ff3ff588

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669):     x24  00000079ff3ff588  x25  00000079ff3fd970  x26  0000007a0078d001  x27  0000007a007240b8

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669):     x28  00000079ff3fd420  x29  00000079ff3fcbc0  x30  0000007a9e0e64d0

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669):     sp   00000079ff3fcb80  pc   0000007a9e0e64f0  pstate 0000000060000000

09-21 08:11:40.469: E/CRASH(15669): backtrace:

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #00  pc 000000000000068c  [vdso] ()

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #01  pc 00000000000224ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+108)

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #02  pc 0000000000022874  /system/lib64/libc.so (__assert2+52)

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #03  pc 0000000000b073d8  /data/app/com.Company.Game-MboFrn89773Nfmb54RA7zA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #04  pc 0000000000b150ac  /data/app/com.Company.Game-MboFrn89773Nfmb54RA7zA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #05  pc 0000000000b14a08  /data/app/com.Company.Game-MboFrn89773Nfmb54RA7zA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #06  pc 0000000000b26474  /data/app/com.Company.Game-MboFrn89773Nfmb54RA7zA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #07  pc 0000000000aad424  /data/app/com.Company.Game-MboFrn89773Nfmb54RA7zA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #08  pc 0000000000654c94  /data/app/com.Company.Game-MboFrn89773Nfmb54RA7zA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #09  pc 00000000006b5b6c  /data/app/com.Company.Game-MboFrn89773Nfmb54RA7zA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #10  pc 00000000006b64bc  /data/app/com.Company.Game-MboFrn89773Nfmb54RA7zA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #11  pc 00000000006c40d4  /data/app/com.Company.Game-MboFrn89773Nfmb54RA7zA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk ()

09-21 08:11:40.495: E/CRASH(15669):     #12  pc 0000000000000d7c  /data/app/com.Company.Game-MboFrn89773Nfmb54RA7zA==/oat/arm64/base.odex ()
```

unity Tags again:

```
09-21 08:19:09.582: I/Unity(16067): SystemInfo CPU = ARM64 FP ASIMD AES, Cores = 4, Memory = 5738mb

09-21 08:19:09.582: I/Unity(16067): SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 2 big (mask: 0xc), 2 little (mask: 0x3)

09-21 08:19:09.583: I/Unity(16067): ApplicationInfo com.Company.Game version 0.12 build 8c1bcf0b-b913-4f07-be91-f94b598dbf47

09-21 08:19:09.583: I/Unity(16067): Built from '2019.2/staging' branch, Version '2019.2.0f1 (20c1667945cf)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a', Stripping 'Disabled'
```

some Info:

Using a OnePlus 3T

- Using Unity 2019.2.0f1 (but had been using this for a while and it was working, no recent upgrades)
- It runs on ARM64
- In order to upload to the app store i have disabled x86 in my build package.
- Causes the same issue on a different windows phone (not sure what friends phone version is, but its not a OnePlus)
- Will break every time on open when opened from the app store
- If i build the file as a .apk i can build, move to my phone, install and load without issue
- build and run with APK works the same
- build and run with AAB works the same
- build and place on the app store, then download from there and  install gives the error.
- I've downloaded Bluestacks on my computer and that works fine.
- Most of the issues i've found online suggest an out of date Firebase SDK, i'm not using Firebase, i use Gamesparks for my    backend.

My config below:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36sCD.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5ijx.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2fu6.png)

As far as i am aware there's nothing that i have specifically changed to cause this error. I would like to resolve the original error so i'm not having to change my compiler and stripping options as it increases the file size to 44+MB instead of 20MB on the app store.

I've been looking at this one for... a few days now, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Anyone got any thing i could try for this issue?

Comment: Hi All, unfortuantely i'm still stuck on this one. I'm really at the final build before the game is able to go live so it's extremely frustrating. if anyone is able to give me any debug steps, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

Unfortunately that took me a couple of months but after doing some reading on SigSev Errors it looks like they are basically calls to things that are nulls and then crashes games. There's a bit more to it, but from that I realized I wasn't really going to get any help with a 90% finished project because it could be anything.

Because I wasn't receiving errors in my code, I assumed it had to be something integrating, most of my focus has been on working with Gamesparks but I added in unity IAP and unityads without really understanding them much.

It looks like I was using in package manager 'Ads' version 2.0.8, this had been replaced a while back with 'Advertisements' version 3.3.1.

Once I added that in, there was a couple obsolete calls around ShowResult and I had to add using UnityEngine.Monetization; instead of UnityEngine.Advertisements. That was just following the most up to date official documentation.

I still have an error around my IAP, but that doesn't seem to crash the game anymore; I've published an AAB on google play, downloaded it and it works :)

Unfortunately, I dont feel this solution will help anyone but me, but maybe it might for someone one day.